# Python Tkinter change all colors of a rectangle list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I try to display some rectangles and to detect if they are double-clicked. The problem is that I can change the color of one rectangle with CURRENT, but when I try to change all rectangles with a tag I have this error: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "3"

Here is a part of my code:

```
number = 10
self.screen_rect = [None for i in range(number)]
for n in range(number):
    self.screen_rect[n] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color, activefill='blue', tags="my_tag")
    self.canvas.tag_bind(self.screen_rect[n], '<Double-1>', self.on_screen_click)

def on_screen_click(self, evt=None):
    print(evt.widget.find_closest(evt.x, evt.y))
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas.find_withtag("my_tag"), fill='blue')#<-- this line has a problem
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT), fill='orange')#<-- this line works
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I am sorry if the code is not understandable for you, but I didn't wanted to put 1000 lines of codes in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer! It was just a for loop missing

```
for elem in self.canvas.find_withtag("my_tag"):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(elem, fill='blue')
```